# How can I transform or query JSON data in my Github Workflow?

Tags: python, json, github-actions, github-api

I am using the `octokit/request-action` action in my Github Workflow to [obtain information about a certain Github Release via its tag name](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-release-by-tag-name):

```yaml
- name: Get Release Info
  uses: octokit/request-action@v2.x
  id: release
  with:
    route: GET /repos/{org_repo}/releases/tags/{tag}
```

The response JSON structure contains information about all of the assets attached to the release. I need to use this information to build a list of download URLs for all the release artifacts and pass that into a Python script that builds a discord notification.

Using the Github Workflow YAML, how do I "query" the JSON data (similar to [JSONata](https://jsonata.org/)) to obtain a list of all the `browser_download_url` values inside the `assets` array? The data returned looks like this (trimmed):

```json
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/1",
  "id": 1,
  "assets": [
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/assets/1",
      "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/releases/download/v1.0.0/example1.zip",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/releases/assets/2",
      "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/releases/download/v1.0.0/example2.zip",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

The end result I want is a way to pass the two download URLs above to my script like so (using a separate step in my workflow):

```
python discord_notification.py "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/releases/download/v1.0.0/example1.zip" "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/releases/download/v1.0.0/example2.zip"
```

(Exact syntax can vary; the above snippet is just an example)

It's possible that what I want to do just can't be achieved in the workflow YAML itself. If that's the case, I'd be OK with a solution that involves passing all or part of the response JSON to the Python script and use Python itself to parse the JSON data. I just don't know if Bash adds a layer of complexity that will make passing a multi-line response string as a parameter difficult.

Comment: You can't "use YAML" to process JSON. `jq` is available in the GitHub-hosted runners (and may well be if you're self-hosted), you could use that to extract the values you want.

Comment: By "use YAML" I meant "Do it in the workflow itself", i.e. by running a command, or using the expression syntax, or something along those lines.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you'll post your comment as an answer, I am happy to accept it. I ended up using `jq` and I liked it.